# nginx php-fpm failed to open stream permission denied

Tags: php, nginx, server, debian

I have a php file on my NGINIX(with php-fpm) that create a simple txt file.

```
<?php
$content = "some text here 123 myText.txt";
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/myText.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

But this works only when I give my "www" folder 777 Permission. My Index.php is placed in my www folder.

What is wrong with my user settings on nginix and php-fpm?

Comment: `php-fpm` and `nginx` are running under which user?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After i give ownership of my www folder to my nginx user (as defined in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`), it works!

```
chown -R www-data:www-data www
```

Comment: You're a life saver ... This solved my issue

Comment: Thanks bro, I was searching whole internet